# No MimeMessage content al enviar un SimpleMailMessage

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estoy intentando enviar un mail desde mi web app pero tengo un error muy extraño.

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages:
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
>   nested exception is:  java.io.IOException: No MimeMessage content

Esta es mi clase ***Mail***

```
public class Mail {

    private String from;
    private String subject;
    private String replyTo;
    private String text;
    private String to;

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getReplyTo() {
        return replyTo;
    }

    public void setReplyTo(String replyTo) {
        this.replyTo = replyTo;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public Mail(String from, String subject, String replyTo, String text) {
        this.from = from;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.replyTo = replyTo;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Mail() {
    }

}
```

Mi ***EmailService***

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;

    public void sendSimpleMessage(final Mail mail) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(mail.getFrom());
        message.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        message.setReplyTo(mail.getReplyTo());
        message.setTo(mail.getTo());
        message.setText(mail.getText());
        emailSender.send(message);
    }

}
```

Mi ***controlador***

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactController.class);

    @Autowired
    EmailService emailService;


    @RequestMapping(value= "contact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView contactPage() {
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName(Constants.CONTACT);
        mav.addObject("mail", mail);
        mav.addObject(Constants.TITLE, "Contact");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/contact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendContactEmail(Model model, RedirectAttributes ra) {
        try {
            Mail mail = new Mail();

            mail.setFrom(mail.getFrom());
            mail.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
            mail.setReplyTo(mail.getReplyTo());
            mail.setText(mail.getText());

            mail.setTo("example@example.com");
            emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail);

            LOG.info("Email Successfully Sended");
            ra.addFlashAttribute("success", 1);
            return "redirect:/contact";
        } catch (MailSendException e) {
            ra.addFlashAttribute("error", 1);
            LOG.error("ERROR SENDING EMAIL", e);
            return "redirect:/contact";
        }
    }

}
```

Y mi ***vista***

```
<form th:action="@{/contact}" th:object="${mail}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputName"
            class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right text-sm-center text">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input th:field="*{from}" type="text" class="form-control"
                id="inputName" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputName"
            class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right text-sm-center"> <i
            class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input th:field="*{subject}" type="text" class="form-control"
                id="inputName" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Subject">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail"
            class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right text-sm-center"> <i
            class="fas fa-at"></i>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input th:field="*{replyTo}" type="email" class="form-control"
                id="inputEmail" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputMessage"
            class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right text-sm-center"> <i
            class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea th:field="*{text}" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"
                id="inputMessage" placeholder="Message">
                            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-contact-7technology w-100">
        <span>SEND MESSAGE</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Depurando el codigo me he percatdo de que esta linea

```
mail.setText(mail.getText());
```

Viene null siempre, algo muy raro ya que yo escribo un mensaje en el Textearea. Todos los otros campos llegan perfectamente y si yo a mi método setText le paso un String a la fuerza el mail llega correctamente con ese String, pero evidentemente quiero que el usuario envié un mail con el mensaje que desee.

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

luego de un rato pude solucionarlo con la pista de @abrahamhs :D 
Resulta que a la hora de enviar el formulario por POST me estaba olvidando de hacer uso de la etiqueta @Valid y de pasar mi objeto Mail por alli. De modo que con mi metodo sendContactEmail de mi controlador de la siguiente manera todo funciona

```
@RequestMapping(value="/contact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendContactEmail(@Valid Mail email, Model model, RedirectAttributes ra) {

        try {
            email.setFrom(email.getFrom());
            email.setSubject(email.getSubject());
            email.setReplyTo(email.getReplyTo());
            email.setTo("example@hotmail.com");
            email.setContactMessage(email.getContactMessage());
            emailService.sendSimpleMessage(email);

            ra.addFlashAttribute("success", 1);
            return "redirect:/contact";
        } catch (MailSendException e) {
            ra.addFlashAttribute("error", 1);
            LOG.error("ERROR SENDING EMAIL", e);
            return "redirect:/contact";
        }
    }
```

El resto del código sigue igual.

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien spring. Pero creo que tu problema es en el controler, aqui:

```
Mail mail = new Mail();
mail.setFrom(mail.getFrom());
mail.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
mail.setReplyTo(mail.getReplyTo());
mail.setText(mail.getText());
```

`mail` me parece que tiene que ser inyectado también y con los datos que vienen desde la vista, ya que al crearlo con `new` va vacio (se crea un objeto nuevo) y el error que te sale `No MimeMessage content` es porque tratas de enviar un mail vació. Posiblemente con esto lo inyecte:

```
@autowired
Mail mail;
```

pero como no se muy bien spring desconozco si también le pase los valores correctamente.

Comment: No puedo hacer un autowired de algo que no es un Bean. Cuando creo la instancia de Mail automaticamente luego la lleno con los seters, lo que me parece MUY extraño es que solo el "mensaje" sea el que llega vacio. Lo otro llega 10 puntos.